# Python: Pandas merge on multiple sets of keys

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

I'm trying to merge two data frames on multiple sets of keys. Meaning that I try to merge using first set, then I take what's left unmerged and use the second set and so on to see what's left unmerged after using all possible sets (in order). I was wondering if there's a quicker and more efficient way of doing it. Here's my current code:

```
################# SUBJECT + VISIT + TIME #################

df1['key'] = df1['SUBJECT'] + df1['VISIT'] + df1['TIME']
df2['key'] = df2['Subject'] + df2['VISIT'] + df2['TIME']
part_one = pd.merge(df1, df2, how='inner', on='key')

################# SUBJECT + VISIT + TIMEPOINT #################

df1 = df1[(df1['key'].isin(part_one['key']) == False)]
df2 = df2[(df2['key'].isin(part_one['key']) == False)]
df1['key'] = df1['SUBJECT'] + df1['VISIT'] + df1['TIMEPOINT']
df2['key'] = df2['Subject'] + df2['VISIT'] + df2['TIMEPOINT']
part_two = pd.merge(df1, df2, how='inner', on='key')

################# SUBJECT + DATE + TIME #################

df1 = df1[(df1['key'].isin(part_two['key']) == False)]
df2 = df2[(df2['key'].isin(part_two['key']) == False)]
df1['key'] = df1['SUBJECT'] + df1['DATE'] + df1['TIME']
df2['key'] = df2['Subject'] + df2['DATE'] + df2['TIME']
part_three  = pd.merge(df1, df2, how='inner', on='key')

################# SUBJECT + DATE + TIMEPOINT #################

df1 = df1[(df1['key'].isin(part_three['key']) == False)]
df2 = df2[(df2['key'].isin(part_three['key']) == False)]
df1['key'] = df1['SUBJECT'] + df1['DATE'] + df1['TIMEPOINT']
df2['key'] = df2['Subject'] + df2['DATE'] + df2['TIMEPOINT']
part_four = pd.merge(df1, df2, how='inner', on='key')

################# REMAINING ROWS #################

left_df1 = df1[(df1['key'].isin(part_four['key']) == False)]
left_df2 = df2[(df2['key'].isin(part_four['key']) == False)]
```